# Aggregate function for array union [HIVE]

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to take a union of arrays over a group by clause. Hive doesn't any generic method to aggregate array union.
Is there any solution apart from built-in hive functions.

Example :

```
CREATE TABLE base_table
(
  day string,
  sample_data array<string>
)

SELECT day, ARRAY_UNION(sample_data) FROM
(
SELECT day, sample_data from base_table1
UNION ALL
SELECT day, sample_data from base_table2
)
GROUP BY day
```

Comment: Very, very, very unclear. "union of arrays"? "over a group by"? Please supply a data sample including required result and the relevant code (table definition etc.)

Comment: `SELECT day, COLLECT_LIST(sample_data) FROM
(
SELECT day, sample_data from base_table1
UNION ALL
SELECT day, sample_data from base_table2
)
GROUP BY day`

Comment: You can write a `UDAF` also

Comment: That's what I did.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `collect_list` or `collect_set`

```
SELECT day, COLLECT_LIST(sample_data) FROM
(
  SELECT day, sample_data from base_table1
    UNION ALL
  SELECT day, sample_data from base_table2
)
GROUP BY day
```

Comment: This won't work. I need to run collect_list(array). collect_list doesn't work with complex data types.

Comment: can you add sample input and output data?